# How to activate scroll right and left in selection in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

Hi the question is simple but i havent found the answer

Like here if i don't have the space to expand and want the user to be able to scroll left and right. Is this an option in PowerBi if so how? Up and down is auto

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No scroll unfortunately, Jonas, in these cases I usually play with the indentations (Format -> Items -> Stepped layout indentation) and/or adjust the font. Splitting the slicer into several (year, month, etc.) and placing them under each other might also work.